# MongoDB not respecting $set { name: "a value" } in update query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing my own API in express to perform mongo update queries and I'm having trouble updating the "name" field specifically.

```
TagHandles.update(
  {"uuid":req.params.id},
  // {$set: { name : "piers" } },
  {$set: { type : "works" } },
  {upsert:true,safe:false},
  function(err, data){
     if (err){
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
     } else {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
     }
     res.send(err || data);
  });
```

The TagHandles is a mongoose model with the following Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var TagHandle = new Schema({
    type: String,
    uuid: String,
    handle: String
}, {
    collection: 'tagHandles'
});
var TagHandles = mongoose.model('tagHandles', TagHandle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently mongoose prevents you from updating any fields not listed as part of the schema. So to correct, I added the line:

```
name: String
```

to the mongoose schema.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature !